# Custom help messages for every WaterfallStep

Tags: asp.net-core, botframework

I'm developing a bot which dialogs are almost exclusively WaterfallDialogs.

They extend the `CancelAndHelpDialog` from the samples that contains the `InterruptAsync` method, this method is called from `OnBeginDialogAsync`:

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> InterruptAsync(DialogContext innerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (innerDc.Context.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        var text = innerDc.Context.Activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant();
        switch (text)
        {
            case "help":
            case "?":
                await ShowHelpAsync(/*-- pass WaterfallStepContext here --*/)
                return new DialogTurnResult(DialogTurnStatus.Waiting);
            case "cancel":
            case "quit":
                await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Cancelling", cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
                return await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I want to declare a method that's gonna display help messages depending on the `WaterfallStepContext.Index` property, and the child dialogs are gona override it, something like that:

```cs
protected async Task ShowHelpAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext)
{
    switch(stepContext.Index)
    {
        case 0:
            //Send help message for step 0.
        ...
    }
};
```

The method will be called inside the `InterruptAsync` method. 
How can I get the WaterfallStepContext from the child dialog in `CancelAndHelpDialog`?
I tried to check if `innerDc` was of runtime type `WaterfallStepContext` without success.

I know I could save the stepContext in storage and retrieve it using the ConversationState accessor, but I would have to do it in every WaterfallStep.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean the child dialog will override the parent dialog (i.e. the dialog that spawned the child dialog)? The idea behind the `CancelAndHelpDialog` is, as a component dialog, it is called, does stuff, and then passes control back to the parent dialog removing itself from the stack (depending on your logic). For instance, a main step could initiate a component dialog to gather information from the user and return that data object back to the parent. Or, perhaps the component dialog can't validate some user, so after informing the user, `cancelAllDialogs()`.

Comment: That was an idea. Having this `ShowHelpAsync` method that each child dialog would implement differently to have separate help messages for every different Dialog. But maybe it's not the right answer. What I would like to achieve is displaying different help messages depending on the WaterfallStep the user was in when he typed "help".

Comment: Have you tried getting the step index of the dialog via `context.ActiveDialog.State["stepIndex"]`. Along with `context.ActiveDialog.id` you can then know which dialog and step you are in, and if you use a switch statement in your help function, I believe you could display a dynamic help message.